# Lead creation by process builder ignores lead assignment rule

Tags: process-builder, assignment-rules

I'm using process builder to create a new lead record if specific status from a custom object record is selected.  Everything works but upon lead creation, the lead assignment rule is not working.

I created a new test lead and upon conversion the lead assignment rule takes place and reassigns the owner of the lead - so the lead assignment is active and working.

Anyone know why lead creation by process builder is bypassing the lead assignment rule?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it appears that is a current limitation for the process builder according to the idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DkvFAAS). Definitely go vote it up and maybe join the group that the PM suggested.